# FirebaseFirestore document not deleted

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a very anxious and bad experience since 02 days with my FiresFirebase Firestore.
Before this, everything was perfect, but since 02 days, I'm not able anymore to delete the document in my database.

I first noticed that the document was no longer erased by the application by the app process needed.

Then i tried directly to erase the document, i was very surprise. When i delete the doc, firstly the docs has been deleted, but after  some times the same docs appear again.

I have looked the rules, evrything is fine as the google documentation recommanded, and the thing is, i worked with my app project like that before without any problem... but sudundly this one appear and i don't understant why.

Please, can you help me to fix this, I'm about to finalize this app, and before fix that ..... I can't do anything !!!!

PLEASE HELP ME ......

Comment: Show us your code that produces that behavior.

Comment: Alex Mamo, before check to code, I have tried to delete manually directly, but nothing ... as I told, when I delete it's looking like it's fine, but after all document deleted appear again like I did't do anything !!!!!! how is possible ?

Comment: @Alex Mamo - it's looking